# Getting 401 error when including parameter in Route attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I keep getting a 401 unauthorized error when accessing my web api controller's get method with a parameter.

I need to send a start date and an end date to the Get function. I've wrapped the dates in an object called `dateParams`.

If I don't include the parameter in the Route attribute of the Get function then I can access it fine without any 401 errors but `dateParams` is null. If I include the parameter in the Route attribute then I get the 401 error.

This works with no errors, but `dateParams` is null:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/rawdatareport")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateParams dateParams) {
             return Ok();
        }
```

This throws a 401 error:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/rawdatareport/{dateParams}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateParams dateParams) {
             return Ok();
        }
```

This is what the `DateParams` class looks like:

```
    public class DateParams {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `[FromUri]` attribute to your action argument:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/rawdatareport/")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] DateParams dateParams) {
    return Ok();
}
```

And send it as a query string argument on your get request

Comment: Can you send a JSON object as a querystring parameter?

Comment: why do you need it to be a json object?

Comment: dateParams is an object that is sent from AngularJS. Besides how else would I send it?

Comment: Adding `[FromUri]` gives me a 405 instead of 401 with the error message being: `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.`